# OpenERP with many2one

Tags: odoo

I've searched through the forums and tried all the solutions I've found, but nothing untill yet.
I've currently this:

```
class open_classB(osv.osv):
    _name = "open.classB"
    _rec_name = 'desc'
    _columns = {
        'desc':fields.char("Description:", size = 50, required = True),
    }
open_classB()
class open_classA(osv.osv):
    _name = 'open.classA'
    _columns = {
                 'notes':fields.text('Notes:'),
                'desc_id':fields.many2one('open.classB', 'Description:', 'desc'),
               }
open_classA()
```

And instead of the dropdown show something like:
'Yellow' ; 'Blue';
It shows: 'open.classB, 1' ; 'open.classB, 2'
I already tried to put the "_rec_name" also on "open_classA", but it's the same.

And in the XML, I only put:

```
<field name="desc_id"/>
```

thanks.

Comment: I think your code is perfact, should not any problem arise. Can you send your code.

Comment: Hello, my original code is equal to the example I put above, but with others "terms". But if you want the original code I've no problem.






Edit: I'm currently editing this post.

Comment: you can send me at: **james.bale.me@gmail.com**

Comment: You can view the code in the pastebin - http://pastebin.com/QfCQirpd

I would like to solve the problem here so others can view it..but if you want I can send you an email.

Comment: I just solved the issue. I had a file called open_classB.py which was making confusing to the main.py. 
The code I posted it's working. Thanks.